# Carrossel com 2 slide

Tags: carousel

Sou leigo no assunto e preciso de um carrossel slider com duas imagens.

Estou usando o copiado do http://plnkr.co/edit/Fl0HZaU5x5ZkPEVo87u3?p=preview .

Neste exemplo aparece 3 imagens e quero que apareça somente dois por causa do espaço que tenho.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado
Rico

Comment: O que você até agora para ajustá-lo conforme sua necessidade?

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/), veja este exemplo de [carousel](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html), basta alterar a quantidade de itens.

Comment: Bruno, gostei, mas não consegui colocar texto, imagem e link juntos. Desculpe sou novato nesta área. Tentei usar <div></div> entre <li>, mas não consegui. A idéia é fazer imagem pequena e texto abaixo dando informações sobre a imagem com botão de "detalhes"

Comment: Você vai precisar "estilizar" o texto para que funcione.

Answer (score -3):

Utilizando o [FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) com somente 2 imagens e contendo texto dentro da imagem, o resultado seria parecido com este exemplo:

http://jsbin.com/jubodi/4/edit?html,css,output

Será necessário fazer ajustes no estilo para conseguir chegar ao que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou muito bem. Os ajustes CSS eu sei fazer.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo!